# Check condition in Render function

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native and have a functionality like image change if Bool value is true otherwise show the default image.But how can i check and set the image in render function of react-native

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for this:

```
render() {
    let image = this.state.bool ? 'true.jpg' : 'false.jpg';
    return <Image source={require(image)} />
}
```

[Here's the doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html)